# How do I get Wordpress to recognize relative URL links on pages?

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to do a seemingly easy thing...to put a relative URL link on a page:

Page: mysite.com/seattle
Relative URL on Page: /office

This should create the link: mysite.com/seattle/office
But instead, it creates: mysite.com/office

In the example above, I need to do this for many cities, so I just want to create 1 relative link "/office" for the many cities, vs creating a unique absolute link for each city. Any ideas? Wondering if there's a Wordpress setting to not override the relative link with the base link.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a WordPress specific thing, this is just relating to how hrefs work in HTML.

Remove the slash from the beginning of your relative link. Instead of /office, use just office. The slash at the beginning of the relative href tells the browser to start at the root of the domain. While omitting the slash tells the browser to start at whatever the current directory path is.

Comment: Oh geez do I feel dumb. Thanks!